# Constants Table Design MySQL Best Practice

Tags: mysql, database-design, sqldatatypes

I need to store a set of 'weight' constants, that will change periodically, which are to be used within some calculations. Which of the following is the better table design, or neither!

**This is what I need to store:**

```
Month Weight (%)
Jan 5
Feb 5
Mar 10
Apr 10
May 10
Jun 10
Jul 10
Aug 10
Sep 10
Oct 10
Nov 5
Dec 5
```

**A table with 1 row and 12 columns:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `constant_month` (
  `month_01` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_02` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_03` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_04` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_05` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_06` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_07` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_08` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_09` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_10` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_11` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `month_12` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

A table with 12 rows and 6 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `constant_month` (
  `constant_month_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The second option allows for more info but it isn't necessarily required.

Expanding this question what happens if the constants I need to store are different data types? In this case they are all percentages but I have another constants table which requires mixed data types. Is option 1 better where I can set the data type specifically for each constant (a mix of INT, DECIMAL and FLOAT) or use option 2 with a generic TEXT data type?

Thanks

Comment: Well you could be tempted to go with a “12 columns” approach here in this specific instance, because it is unlikely that our current system of having twelve Months in a year will change any time soon. But in general, you should rather normalize this - and that’s what I would recommend here, too. (Mainly out of principle, because doing it _differently_ in the next comparable situation that just happens not to have a fixed number of such values, would be a rather bad “mix”. IMHO.)

Comment: And if you need to store arbitrary values of different types, then you could either go with one column per possible type - but then I would probably add an additional one that holds information about the type, so that you would know which of those other columns to look in. But you would still need some kind of conditional logic using control flow functions, to get the data out of the correct type column. [...]

Comment: [...] It might make more sense in such a case to go with a “general” text type, that can also hold things such as numbers, dates, etc. in the right formatting. (Since this is for _storage_ of constants only, I don’t assume you will need to perform any kind of “advanced” operations on those records, that would need the “proper” column type to work.)

Comment: Hi CBroe. Thanks for your insight. I posted the question because I was uncomfortable about the 12 column approach and you have made my mind up that this is not a 'good' approach. What data type would you suggest for a 'general' text type; would VARCHAR(25) be sufficient do you think? Thanks

Comment: With VARCHAR you can usually be more “generous” - it will only use about as much storage space as you actually put characters in it, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings So if you store 10 characters into a VARCHAR(255) column, that will still take only 10+1 bytes of actual storage. But you’d have the “reserve” to handle longer values built-in.

Answer (score 0):

- "generic TEXT data type" -- bad, especially if you need to compare numeric values.
- Splaying an array across columns -- bad.  (The 1-row 12-col approach).
- Do you need all 6 columns in your 12x6 approach?